# Combining Images in CameraView with Overlay. (Swift 3)?

Tags: ios, swift3, camera-overlay

I just about have this solved. Thanks to some brilliant help getting me on the right track.
This is the code I have now.

Basically, I can now make an image out of the drawn overlay, and the cameraPreview. But can't yet combine them. There seems very little useful code that I can find that does this simply.

So the important part is the extension block right at the top, and the additions to the 
func saveToCamera() near the bottom of the code.
In short, I now have the two images I need, I think. The snap of the myImage is appearing on a white background - so not sure if that's natural - or not. That's how it appears on a Simulator. So it may just be natural.

Image 1. A screen capture.
[image: ScreenCapture of running app]

Image 2. The saved image of myImage as per the explaination.
[image]

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Foundation

// extension must be outside class
extension UIImage {
convenience init(view: UIView) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    self.init(cgImage: (image?.cgImage)!)
}
}




class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!
@IBOutlet weak var imgOverlay: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var btnCapture: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var shapeLayer: UIView!


let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

//var shapeLayer : CALayer?

// If we find a device we'll store it here for later use
var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //=======================

    let midX = self.view.bounds.midX
    let midY = self.view.bounds.midY

    for index in 1...10 {
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: midX,y: midY), radius: CGFloat((index * 10)), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
    let shapeLayerPath = CAShapeLayer()

    shapeLayerPath.path = circlePath.cgPath
    //change the fill color
    shapeLayerPath.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    //you can change the stroke color
    shapeLayerPath.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    //you can change the line width
    shapeLayerPath.lineWidth = 0.5

        // add the blue-circle layer to the shapeLayer ImageView
        shapeLayer.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayerPath)

    }
    print("Shape layer drawn")
    //=====================



    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

    if let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices() as? [AVCaptureDevice] {
        // Loop through all the capture devices on this phone
        for device in devices {
            // Make sure this particular device supports video
            if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
                // Finally check the position and confirm we've got the back camera
                if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back) {
                    captureDevice = device
                    if captureDevice != nil {
                        print("Capture device found")
                        beginSession()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func actionCameraCapture(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    print("Camera button pressed")
    saveToCamera()
}

func beginSession() {

    do {
        try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
        stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]

        if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
        }

    }
    catch {
        print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    guard let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) else {
        print("no preview layer")
        return
    }
    // this is what displays the camera view. But - it's on TOP of the drawn view, and under the overview. ??
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame



    captureSession.startRunning()
    print("Capture session running")


    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
    //self.view.addSubview(imgOverlay)
    self.view.addSubview(btnCapture)

    // shapeLayer ImageView is already a subview created in IB
    // but this will bring it to the front
    self.view.addSubview(shapeLayer)

        }

func saveToCamera() {

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
          stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (CMSampleBuffer, Error) in

            if let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(CMSampleBuffer) {
                if let cameraImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                    // cameraImage is the camera preview image.

                    // I need to combine/merge it with the myImage that is actually the blue circles.

                    // This converts the UIView of the bllue circles to an image. Uses 'extension' at top of code.
                    let myImage = UIImage(view: self.shapeLayer)
                    print("converting myImage to an image")


                   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(cameraImage, nil, nil, nil)

                }
            }
        })
    }
}






override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try... instead of combining your overlay view, it draws the circles and combines the output:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Foundation

class CameraWithTargetViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgOverlay: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnCapture: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var shapeLayer: UIView!

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    //var shapeLayer : CALayer?

    // If we find a device we'll store it here for later use
    var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //=======================

        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

        if let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices() as? [AVCaptureDevice] {
            // Loop through all the capture devices on this phone
            for device in devices {
                // Make sure this particular device supports video
                if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
                    // Finally check the position and confirm we've got the back camera
                    if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back) {
                        captureDevice = device
                        if captureDevice != nil {
                            print("Capture device found")
                            beginSession()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func actionCameraCapture(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        print("Camera button pressed")
        saveToCamera()
    }

    func beginSession() {

        do {
            try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
            stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]

            if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
                captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
            }

        }
        catch {
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        guard let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) else {
            print("no preview layer")
            return
        }
        // this is what displays the camera view. But - it's on TOP of the drawn view, and under the overview. ??
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame


        imgOverlay.frame = self.view.frame
        imgOverlay.image = self.drawCirclesOnImage(fromImage: nil, targetSize: imgOverlay.bounds.size)

        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: navigationBar)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: imgOverlay)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: btnCapture)
        // don't use shapeLayer anymore...
        //      self.view.bringSubview(toFront: shapeLayer)


        captureSession.startRunning()
        print("Capture session running")

    }

    func getImageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height))
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }

    func drawCirclesOnImage(fromImage: UIImage? = nil, targetSize: CGSize? = CGSize.zero) -> UIImage? {

        if fromImage == nil && targetSize == CGSize.zero {
            return nil
        }

        var tmpimg: UIImage?

        if targetSize == CGSize.zero {

            tmpimg = fromImage

        } else {

            tmpimg = getImageWithColor(color: UIColor.clear, size: targetSize!)

        }

        guard let img = tmpimg else {
            return nil
        }

        let imageSize = img.size
        let scale: CGFloat = 0
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, scale)

        img.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)

        let w = imageSize.width

        let midX = imageSize.width / 2
        let midY = imageSize.height / 2

        // red circles - radius in %
        let circleRads = [ 0.07, 0.13, 0.17, 0.22, 0.29, 0.36, 0.40, 0.48, 0.60, 0.75 ]

        // center "dot" - radius is 1.5%
        var circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: midX,y: midY), radius: CGFloat(w * 0.015), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

        UIColor.red.setFill()
        circlePath.stroke()
        circlePath.fill()

        // blue circle is between first and second red circles
        circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: midX,y: midY), radius: w * CGFloat((circleRads[0] + circleRads[1]) / 2.0), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

        UIColor.blue.setStroke()
        circlePath.lineWidth = 2.5
        circlePath.stroke()

        UIColor.red.setStroke()

        for pct in circleRads {

            let rad = w * CGFloat(pct)

            circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: midX, y: midY), radius: CGFloat(rad), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

            circlePath.lineWidth = 2.5
            circlePath.stroke()

        }

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage
    }

    func saveToCamera() {

        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
            stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (CMSampleBuffer, Error) in

                if let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(CMSampleBuffer) {
                    if let cameraImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {

                        if let nImage = self.drawCirclesOnImage(fromImage: cameraImage, targetSize: CGSize.zero) {
                            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(nImage, nil, nil, nil)
                        }

                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for that. Now I have two ways of achieving much the same result.  I got caught with the class declaration at first - class CameraWithTargetViewController: UIViewController { - but that was all. The circles mage is over the top of the Navigation Bar - but that's no issue. I'll need to study this today, It does everything I want too. This "func drawCirclesOnImage("  is really interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved it pretty much. The important code is here. The resulting image is slightly out of skew, but I'll work away and fix that, unless someone can see a good fix for it.

```
    func saveToCamera() {

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
          stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (CMSampleBuffer, Error) in

            if let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(CMSampleBuffer) {
                if let cameraImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                    // cameraImage is the camera preview image.

                    // I need to combine/merge it with the myImage that is actually the blue circles.

                    // This converts the UIView of the bllue circles to an image. Uses 'extension' at top of code.
                    let myImage = UIImage(view: self.shapeLayer)
                    print("converting myImage to an image")

                    let newImage = self.composite(image:cameraImage, overlay:(myImage), scaleOverlay:true)
                   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage!, nil, nil, nil)

                }
            }
        })
    }
}

func composite(image:UIImage, overlay:(UIImage), scaleOverlay: Bool = false)->UIImage?{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
    var rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
    image.draw(in: rect)
    if scaleOverlay == false {
        rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: overlay.size.width, height: overlay.size.height)
    }
    overlay.draw(in: rect)
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
```

The resulting saved image.

[image: Slightly out of skey, but working]

Comment: I've just noticed that the display and image sizes are incorrect for an iPad (mini), probably any iPad. The visual, and saved images size is 1080x1920 - iPhone 6S Plus size. Deployment info is set to Universal.

Comment: So it could be the overlay size for the circles is fixed in place. Now where do I find that.