# How to add current timestamp in camera in ios app

Tags: ios, camera, timestamp, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition

[image]

Something like this I want to add current timestamp when recording is done in the video and save into camera roll.

**Note **: I have successfully added current location and timestamp in AVVideoPreviewLayer but it is static after exporting video is show static time does not show running timestamp

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a layer of previewLayer: UIView with the components you want to have on camera.

Add this layer to currently running session of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.

This link might help you to achieve your problem

[Adding objects over camera view in app (Swift 3) not under camera view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579545/adding-objects-over-camera-view-in-app-swift-3-not-under-camera-view)

Answer (score 1):

I tried something out. I guess you want to get latitude, longitude and the timestamp.

You find an example for latitude and longitude below.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func showLocation(_ sender: Any) {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        if(CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()){
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

        print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
    {
         print("Error \(error)")
    }
}
```

To get the current time you can use something like this:

```
let date = NSDate()
print(date)
```

The result for both in console should look something like this:

```
2017-12-17 21:45:39 +0000
user latitude = 37.3322499
user longitude = -122.056264
```

(The time looks like this in my example because im from EU but you can convert it to what you want)

You can add this to a separate view and bring it to front with

```
view.bringSubview(toFront: YourView)
```

I hope this is helpful!